# In R, split a column in 2 columns based on some condition

Tags: r, split, multiple-columns

I am trying to split data frame hire into 2 columns based of percentage.

### | group     | percentage|

|0 hired    |            60% |

| 0 hired next_month |    65% |

| 0 or 1 hired        |    68% |

| 0 or 1 hired next_month |       70%|

|1  hired   |                       79%|

|1 or 2 employee |                  80%|

|2 retired|                         85%|

|2 or 3 fired|                      92%|

|3 not-retired|                     96%|

- I want 2 columns group and decision output should be (column percentage and decision should be as it is no change, column group should be 0 if percentage is between 60% to 69% (3rd row), group should be 1 if percentage is between 70% to 79% (4th row), group should be 2 if percentage is between 80% to 89%, group should be 3 if percentage is between 90% to 99% )

|  group    |     decision    |               percentage

---

| 0        |     hired        |              60%

|  0        |     hired next_month |          65%

|  0        |     hired            |          68%

|  1        |     hired next_month   |        70%

|  1        |     hired              |        79%

|2 |  employee |                  80%|

|2 | retired|                         85%|

|3 | fired|                      92%|

|3 |not-retired|                     96%|

my code:
              foo<-str_split_fixed(hire$group, "or", 2)

can anyone help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`, `extract` (from `tidyr`) to split 'group' into 'group' and 'decision', then `replace` the 'group' value to 1 if the 'percentage' (extracted the number with `parse_number` from `readr`) is greater than or equal to 90.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    extract(group, into = c('group', 'decision'), "^(\\d+).*(hired.*)") %>% 
    mutate(group = replace(group, parse_number(percentage)>=90, 1))
#    group         decision percentage
#1     0            hired        80%
#2     0 hired next_month        85%
#3     0            hired        88%
#4     1 hired next_month        90%
#5     1            hired        99%
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c("0 hired", "0 hired next_month", "0 or 1 hired", 
"0 or 1 hired next_month", "1 hired"), percentage = c("80%", 
"85%", "88%", "90%", "99%")), .Names = c("group", "percentage"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks alot but actually data has more columns and (hired.*) doesnot work here. sorry can you suggest me something else. I am editing data in orignal question.

Comment: I have modified your code for new problem but I am having trouble with parse_number can you help.  df1 %>%
  extract(group, into = c('group', 'decision'), "^(\\d+).*(hired|hired next_month|employee|retired|fired|not-retired)") %>% 
  mutate(group = replace(group, parse_number(if((percentage)>=90) 1 else 0)))

Comment: I have further modified it but still not getting desired output    - df2<-df1 %>% extract(group, into = c('group', 'decision'), "^(\\d+).*(hired|hired next_month|employee|retired|fired|not-retired)")%>% 
 mutate(group = replace(group, parse_number(percentage)>=90, 3))

Comment: @Jals It is based on your example I created the pattern